# How can I show and hide a png using a hot key in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to show and hide a png (With no frame, margin, or title bar) but can't find a good way to do it. I tried using matplotlib but the code has to be in the main thread so I can't figure out how to use functions to show or hide it. I also tried tkinter but ran into the same problem where calling it from a function the code would just stop when trying to call it from a function.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Below is what I am trying to accomplish though the code doesn't display any image. The code doesn't return an error either, it just stops executing at mainloop without displaying anything unless the code is in the main thread.

```
#Import modules
import os #For working directory
from pynput import keyboard #For hotkeys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

#Set default directory
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Python')

#Define global variables
global img

#Functions
def ExitProgram():
    print('test')
    #sys.exit(0)
    quit() #Will not work in production, switch to sys.exit
    return

def ShowImage():
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
    canvas.pack()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("menu.png"))
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)
    root.overrideredirect(True)  # removes title bar
    root.mainloop()
    print('test')
    return

#Define hotkeys
with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+q': ExitProgram,
        '<ctrl>+0': ShowImage}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Comment: You need to say `global img` inside of `def ShowImage()`. And there is no need for using an external library for binding to keys, you can use `bind()` of tkinter itself. I dont think the GUI will appear at all, because the program doesnt get focus at all.

Comment: @CoolCloud Since `root.mainloop()` will block the application until the root window is destroyed, that means the function will not return as long as the root window is alive.  So `global img` is not necessary.  OP uses external library to do system-wise hotkeys that tkinter `bind()` cannot fulfill.